# Sharing App on Facebook + Video

Tags: facebook

I am launching an app today, and would like to share it on Facebook. I also have a video I have made to go along with it to use as promo. Is it possible to have a video embedded in the post, that then links to the app store link? I assume this is using meta, I have tried using:

`og:title`,`og:site_name`,`al:ios:app_name`,`og:video:url`,`al:ios:app_store_id`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Open Graph specification for the correct OG tags: http://ogp.me/#type_video

There is also an example if you scroll up:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/movie.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/movie.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300" />
```

Comment: This will provide the video, but is there a way to get the link to go to the app store?

Comment: i don´t think so, no. after all it´s a video, if you click on it, it will just start. else you could just use a picture instead ;)